# How can I remove the current cell focus from A Windows Forms datagridview?

Tags: .net, datagridview

How can I remove the current cell focus from a Windows Forms datagridview ?
I have a dialog with some datagridforms and initially I don't want to have a cell selection.
Actually in every gridview the cell [1,1] is selected

I have already searched in some forums, but the provided solutions doesn't work.
For example often it is recommended to set CurrentCell = null --> but this has no effect. 
Has anybody another solution, which really works ;-) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
if (dataGridView.RowCount > 0 && dataGridView.ColumnCount >0)
{
   dataGridView.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView[0, 0];
   this.dataGridView.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
dataGridView.ClearSelection();
dataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
```